# Join 2 tables with no equal key

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, one contains subscription numbers with an start and end date.

One is just a calendar which contain one month in each line (202104, 202201, etc.).

My goal is for each month in the calendar table, calculate the number of active subscription so I will have to, for each month, count distinct subscription numbers which have start month <= that month and end month > that month or end month is null.

Here is the code that I came up with but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT  
    d."Year_Month", a."brand", a."gender", a."unique_name",
    COUNT(DISTINCT a."subscription_id")
FROM 
    date AS d,
    subscriptions AS a
WHERE
    d."Year_Month" >= a."Year_month_start"
    AND (d."Year_Month" <= a."Year_month_end"
         OR a.Year_month_end IS NULL)
GROUP BY 
    d."Year_Month", a."brand", a."gender", a."unique_name"
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: Which sql dialect are you working with? What kind of errors / incorrect results does your query produce? The more info you can provide the better, eg. the definitions of the tables involved.

Comment: *Doesn't work* tells us nothing. Please read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).. TAG your specific RDBMS.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - it might work (can't be sure, since your tables structure is not fully clear)

```
SELECT  
    d."Year_Month", a."brand", a."gender", a."unique_name",
    COUNT(DISTINCT a."subscription_id")
FROM 
    date AS d,
    subscriptions AS a

WHERE  
    to_char(d."Year_Month",'YYYYMM') = to_char(a."Year_month_start",'YYYYMM')
    AND 
   ( to_char(d."Year_Month",'YYYYMM') = to_char(a."Year_month_end",'YYYYMM')
         OR a.Year_month_end IS NULL )

GROUP BY 
    d."Year_Month", a."brand", a."gender", a."unique_name"
```